# How to fill a panel with an Ext.Img

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have tried many ways to make an Ext.Img fill its parent panel. What I have seen is the large image cut off by the panels space, not centered. One configuration the image displayed dynamically reduced in size but only inside Chrome, but the image disappeared on the iPad2.

The layout is a panel with a docked toolbar and an image inside it. Nothing fancy, nothing grand. What am I missing?

**Update 1:** changed the mode, but only Chrome worked. The iPad showed nothing at all.

```
mode: 'image',
centered: true,
height: '100%'
```

Comment: Could you post the code you tried so we can work on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @darmen you can also define into `Ext.Panel` with `style` element, so like this,

```
style: 'backgroundImage:url(your/path/images/file.jpg);backgroundSize:100% 100%;backgroundRepeat:no-repeat;backgroundPosition:top left',
```

**Hope these helps. :)**

Comment: Thank you for that. I also need to dynamically change the image and that appears to make it more challenging to do that. How would you update the url?